# SELECT DISTINCT rows that can occur only once

Tags: postgresql, join, distinct, distinct-values

Let's say we are joining two tables (A and B) by some condition using left or inner join

```sql
WITH
a(id, x) AS (VALUES
    (0, 'a'),
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'b')
),
b(id, y) AS (VALUES
    (10, 'a'),
    (20, 'a'),
    (30, 'b')
),
pairs AS (
    SELECT a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id
    FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.x=b.y
)
SELECT * FROM pairs; -- how to modify this query to return the expected result?
```

The result will be 5 rows (2 * 2 + 1 * 1)
Now the hard part: id from each table can appear in the result only once.

```sql
a_id|b_id|
----|----|
   0|  10|
 ->0|  20| -- a_id=0 can be picked only once
   1|->10| -- b_id=10 can be picked only once
   1|  20|
   2|  30|

-- so the expected result is:
a_id|b_id|
----|----|
   0|  10|
   1|  20|
   2|  30|

-- UPDATE: alternative result could be:
a_id|b_id|
----|----|
   0|  20|
   1|  10|
   2|  30|
```

Comment: I've tried to use sub-queries and `DISTINCT ON` syntax but this was not giving me the expected result

Comment: Why not `(0,20),(1,10),(2,30)`?

Comment: That's another option that satisfies the result. depends on the order but overall it does not matter. Just IDs cannot repeat

Comment: I would change the code for pairs. Is that possible?

Comment: @S-Man yes but does it makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, of course, because now we can modify the tables BEFORE joining ;)

Comment: If it doesn't matter, that is a problem. It *should* matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ab883b2bf9cbb88ac29cddb00c77f697)

After joining the tables is quite hard, I found no fast solution. I guess, that's a combinatorical problem, because the result depends on the order in which you process the data. But if the data changes, the result is completely different... Maybe someone proofs me wrong...

However, if we are able to modify the tables BEFORE joining, it would be much better:

```
WITH
a(id, x) AS (VALUES
    (0, 'a'),
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'b')
),
b(id, y) AS (VALUES
    (10, 'a'),
    (20, 'a'),
    (30, 'b')
),
pairs AS (
    SELECT a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY x)
        FROM
            a
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            *,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY y)
        FROM
            b
    ) b ON a.x=b.y AND a.row_number = b.row_number
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM pairs
```

Now we can add a row count. So we can merge on the data AND the row count. This ensure that every data is merged only once.

Comment: thanks, got a pretty similar solution but need to check that it covers other cases

```sql
pairs AS (
 SELECT a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id
 FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.x=b.y
),
sub AS (
 SELECT
 *,
 rank() OVER (PARTITION BY a_id ORDER BY b_id) rank_a,
 rank() OVER (PARTITION BY b_id ORDER BY a_id) rank_b
 FROM pairs
)
SELECT * FROM sub
WHERE rank_a = rank_b;
```